# Is "status 1" pronounced "status of one"

Tags: pronunciation

[In a tutorial](https://youtu.be/2Fp1N6dof0Y?t=707), it sounds like "non-zero exit status 1" is pronounced "non zero exit status of one", with the pattern `xx of number` when talking about a number-value of something.

Did I hear it correctly?

Is it a general pattern to refer to  a number-value of something?

Comment: No, it is not. The person reading the script tried to clarify, inserting"one" *ad lib*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you. What does "ad lib" mean?

Comment: Ad lib means to improvise something that isn't in a written script or other pre-written material